# Answer Set Programming - make a FACT invalid

Tags: automation, artificial-intelligence, answer-set-programming, clingo

I have a question regarding **Answer Set Programming** on how to make an existing ***fact*** invalid, when there is already (also) a ***default statement*** present in the Knowledge Base.

For example, there are two persons `seby` and `andy`, one of them is able to drive at once. The scenario can be that `seby` can drive as seen in Line 3 but  let's say, after his license is cancelled he cannot drive anymore, hence we now have Lines 4 to 7 and meanwhile `andy` learnt driving, as seen in Line 7. Line 6 shows only one person can drive at a time, besides showing `seby` and `andy` are not the same.

```
1 person(seby).
2 person(andy).
3 drives(seby).
4 drives(seby) :- person(seby), not ab(d(drives(seby))), not -drives(seby).
5 ab(d(drives(seby))).
6 -drives(P) :- drives(P0), person(P), P0 != P.
7 drives(andy).
```

In the above program, Lines 3 and 7 contradict with Line 6, and the Clingo solver (which I use) obviously outputs `UNSATISFIABLE`.

Having said all this, please don't say to delete Line 3 and the problem is solved. The intention behind asking this question is to know whether it is possible now to make Line 3 somehow invalid to let Line 4 do its duty.

However, Line 4 can also be written as:

```
4 drives(P) :- person(P), not ab(d(drives(P))), not -drives(P).
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand the problem. Line 3 and line 4 are separate rules, even if line 4's antecedent is false line 3 would still be true. In other words, line 4 seems redundant.

It seems like you want a choice. I assume ab(d(drives(seby))) denotes that seby has lost their license. So, below line four is your constraint on only people with a license driving. Line five is the choice, so by default andy or seby can drive but not both. Notice in the ground program how line five is equivalent to drives(seby) :- not drives(andy). and drives(andy) :- not drives(seby). You can also have seby as being the preferred driver using optimization statements (the choice rule below is like an optimization statement).

```
person(seby).
person(andy).
ab(d(drives(seby))).
:- person(P), ab(d(drives(P))), drives(P).
1{drives(P) : person(P)}1.
```

Answer (score 0):

If something is true, it must always be true. Therefore the line:

```
drives(seby).
```

will always be true.

However, we can get around this by putting the fact into a choice rule.

```
0{drives(seby)}1.
```

This line says that an answer will have 0 to 1 `drives(seby).`. This means we can have rules that contradict `drives(seby).` and the answer will still be satisfiable, but we can also have `drives(seby).` be true.

Both this program:

```
0{drives(seby)}1.
drives(seby).
```

And this program:

```
0{drives(seby)}1.
:- drives(seby).
```

Are satisfiable.

Most likely you will want `drives(seby).` to be true if it can be, and false if it can't be. To accomplish this, we need to force Clingo into making `drives(seby).` true if it can. We can do this by using an optimization.

A naive way to do this is to count how many `drives(seby).` exist (either 0 or 1) and maximize the count.

We can count the number of `drives(seby).` with this line:

```
sebyCount(N) :- N = #count {drives(seby) : drives(seby)}.
```

N is equal to the number of `drives(seby).` in the domain `drives(seby).`. This will either be 0 or 1.

And then we can maximize the value of N with this statement:

```
#maximize {N@1 : sebyCount(N)}.
```

This maximizes the value of N with the priority 1 (the lower the number, the lower the priority) in the domain of sebyCount(N).